# How to run expo in interactive mode?

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, build, expo

I am curently running into an issue when trying to build my expo app (react-native) for iOS.

When running the command `exp build:ios` I get the folowing error:

```
[18:11:15] Error while gathering & validating credentials
[18:11:15] Input is required, but exp is in non-interactive mode.
Required input:
> How would you like to upload your credentials?
```

It means my expo application is running in non-interactive mode and that is why it cannot accept an input while running. I would like to know how I could fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method for our CI/CD.

You need to run

```
expo build:ios --release-channel deploy-test -c --clear-app-credentials
```

Then

```
expo fetch:ios:certs
```

This command will get the generated certs from expo and will also give 2 passwords. You need to set them as environment variables.

```
EXPO_IOS_DIST_P12_PASSWORD: Distribution p12 password

EXPO_IOS_PUSH_P12_PASSWORD: Push p12 password
```

Now that you have the information to pass to expo with login to apple, use the following command.

```
expo build:ios --no-publish --no-wait --release-channel production --team-id TEAMID --dist-p12-path "PROJECTNAME_dist.p12" --push-p12-path "PROJECTNAME_push.p12"  --provisioning-profile-path "PROJECTNAME.mobileprovision" --non-interactive -c
```

Hopefully this helps!